# How are queues and stacks typically implemented?

Tags: java, data-structures

According to

[Columbia Notes](http://www.cs.nyu.edu/~cconway/teaching/cs1007/notes/data-structures.pdf), page 4 and 5

> We can implement a queue with an array or a linked list.

...

> We can implement a stack with an array or a linked list.

Is it a sinlge linked list or a double linked list?

Also, when is an array used and when is the linked structure used?

Comment: Understand the complexity of operations for Queues and Stacks and for ArrayLists and LinkedLists and you will be able to answer this question yourself. Also look at the source code of the above classes.

Comment: How could you ever use an array?  It is not dynamic.  It can't grow and shrink as you push / pop or add / get.

Comment: You just create a new bigger array and copy over the elements.

Comment: That sounds like an idea that should never be used to implement queues/stacks.

Comment: Under particular sets of circumstances/usage/assumptions, an array isn't such a bad idea. You just need to know how to define said assumptions and identify the circumstances/usages.

Comment: @nativist.bill.cutting- It's all just weighing pros and cons for your specific situation. For example, if the data you're storing in your queue/stack is very small, then the extra memory needed to keep pointers between nodes may be prohibitive. In that case, an array makes sense.

Comment: I've been doing mostly JavaScript, lately but learning Java as this is what is taught in University, so I don't have any "real use" cases for when you are making these kind of design choices.  But I guess they must exist.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Stacks are typically implemented using an arrays.  This is because items are always added/removed from the same end. The other end never moves.

Queues are typically implemented as singly linked lists as this is the simplest implementation.  It can be implemented as an array, but this is harder and was only added in Java in version 6.